# Where to store global settings for my SPItemEventReceivers?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a SPItemEventReceiver that does nothing else than notify another HTTP server at a given IP and Port abouth the events using POST requests.

The HTTP server runs on the same computer as sharepoint, so I used to send the notification at localhost and a fixed Port number. But since the eventreceiver can be called in other servers in the serverfarm, localhost:PORT will not be available then.

So, everytime my HTTP server starts, it needs to save its IP address and Port somewhere in SharePoint where all EventReceivers have access, no matter on what server they are called.

What would be a good place to store such globally available information?

I tought about `SPWebService.ContentService.Properties` , but I'm not really sure if that's a good idea. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually several ways of saving configuration values in SharePoint:

- Property Bags of SharePoint objects `SPWebApplication, SPFarm,`SPSite, SPWeb, SPList, SPListItem`
- A "configuration" list in SharePoint - just a regular list you might set to `Hidden = TRUE`
- The web.config file - specifically the `<AppSettings>`

Wictor Wilen actually explains the [6 ways to store settings in SharePoint](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Six-ways-to-store-settings-in-SharePoint.aspx).

As you are talking about an external process trying to save its settings somewhere, generally I would recommend the web.config, but each change in the web.config would lead to an `IISRESET` making it not a good option. I would strongly advise to use either a property bag (e.g. the `SPWebApplication.Properties` bag) or a hidden list in your favorite web site. You would set the property bag like so:

```
SPWebApplication webApplication = ...
object customObject = ...
// set value in hashtable
webApp.Add("MySetting", customObject);
// persist the hashtable
webApp.Update();
```

See what is cool about this? You can actually store an object with the web application which could contain multiple settings as long as you keep your object serializable.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you are using Sharepoint 2010 I would consider store those values in the property bag. Using client object model or even Javascript/ECMAScript Client Object Model. These codes maybe help you.

```
using (var context = new ClientContext("http://localhost"))
{
  var allProperties = context.Web.AllProperties;
  allProperties["testing"] = "Hello there";
  context.Web.Update();
  context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Or using javascript:

```
    function getWebProperty() {
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootweb();
        this.props =  web.get_allProperties();
        this.props.set_item(“aProperty”, “aValue”);
        ctx.load(web);

        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, gotProperty), Function.createDelegate(this, failedGettingProperty));
    }

    function gotProperty() {
        alert(this.props.get_item(“aProperty”));
    }

    function failedGettingProperty() {
        alert("failed");
    }
```

Sources:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49299/sharepoint-2010-net-client-object-model-add-item-to-web-property-bag

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Making-use-of-the-Property-Bag-in-the-ECMAScript-Client-Object-Model.aspx

Comment: So I would have to store the information on every SPWeb ond every SPSite ond every SPWebApplication in the Farm?

Comment: The property bag can be used at many levels, such as SPWeb, SPSite or even at SPFarm level. Although I have never used at the SPFarm, I'm trying to find some good reference

Comment: These one may help: http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-property-bag-settings/ I would try to write some code example but I have no access to a sharepoint environment right now.

Comment: Sometimes, I wish I could accept multiple answers and not just the one  that showed the one of a lot correct possibilites I finally used...

Comment: @moontear answer was very good and complete, this was actually my first answer on the forum. Still learning!!